# checkbox filters not working as desired in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a requirement to filter some properties using check boxes. Here what I wrote:

js code:

```
app.controller("filterCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: contextPath + '/properties'
})
    .then(function (response) {
        var properties = response.data.properties;
        var propertyFilters = response.data.filters;
        $scope.properties = properties;
        $scope.propertyFilters = propertyFilters;

        $scope.usePropertyGroups = {};
        $scope.usePropertyTypes = {};
        $scope.usePropertyStates = {};

        $scope.$watch(function () {
            return {
                properties: $scope.properties,
                usePropertyGroups: $scope.usePropertyGroups,
                usePropertyTypes: $scope.usePropertyTypes,
                usePropertyStates: $scope.usePropertyStates
            }
        }, function (value) {

            var filterType = [
                {selected : $scope.usePropertyGroups, filterProp : 'propertyGroups'},
                {selected : $scope.usePropertyTypes, filterProp : 'propertyTypes'},
                {selected : $scope.usePropertyStates, filterProp : 'states'}
            ];

             var filteredProps = $scope.propertyVOs;

             for(var i in filterType){
             filteredProps = filterData(filteredProps, filterType[i].selected, filterType[i].filterProp);
             }

            $scope.filteredProps = filteredVOs;

        }, true);

    });
})

var filterData = function(allData,selectedProps,equalData){
var afterFilter = [];
var selected = false;
for (var j in allData) {
    var p = allData[j];
    for (var i in selectedProps) {
        if (selectedProps[i]) {
            selected = true;
            if (i == p[equalData]) {
                afterFilter.push(p);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
if (!selected) {
    afterFilter = allData;
}

return afterFilter;
};
```

html:

```
<div data-ng-controller="filterCtrl">

<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>property ID</th>
            <th>property name</th>
            <th>property description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="vo in filteredProps">
            <td>{{vo.id}}</td>
            <td>{{vo.name}}</td>
            <td>{{vo.description}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="filter-list-container">
        <ul data-ng-repeat="(key,value) in propertyFilters.filterOfGroup">
            <li><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="usePropertyGroups[key]"/>{{key}}<span> ({{value}})</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list-container">
        <ul data-ng-repeat="(key,value) in propertyFilters.filterOfType">
            <li><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="usePropertyTypes[key]"/>{{key}}<span> ({{value}})</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list-container">
        <ul data-ng-repeat="(key,value) in propertyFilters.filterOfStates">
            <li><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="usePropertyStates[key]"/>{{key}}<span> ({{value}})</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I defined three filters (property group, property type, and property state). so whenever user click the corresponding check box, table will show related properties. Everything looks good, the only issue is when I select the first check box (for example property group) table shows lets say 50 property of 100 total. If I click the next one it is filtering the 50 property which I already filtered instead of filtering the whole array (which is 100 properties). I mean I want to filter the whole properties whenever the user checks multiple check boxes. I have worked a lot on filterType loops in the controller to get it done but I couldn't. I really appreciate any help on this. 
I noticed that this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rzgWr/19/) is very similar to my case. if I check one filter from "Pant Size" and one filter from "Shirt Size" it would show just the matched items instead of all items.

Comment: can you provide plunker ? with mock of your http call

Answer (score 0):

i think its filter 1 time 50/100 item 2 time 20/50 remaining 50 witch already filter so you need on every check box click first bind grid then filter it.